# How can I see file content in real time on Linux?

Tags: bash, shell, file

I have a log file which will be write some data in it continuously.

How can I see what data is being written to the file on my Linux terminal without opening the file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`tail`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html)'s `-F` option to *follow* in real time the changes made to your file:

```
tail -F my_file.log
```

---

*Note:* By default, [**`tail`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) prints the last 10 lines of your file. If you want to see more lines you can use the `-n` option:

```
tail -F -n 50 my_file.log  # See the last 50 lines in real time
```

Comment: To see all lines, use `tail -f -n +1 file`.

Answer (score -1):

`tail -f -n 100 filename`

-n 100-> number of previous lines